# What is the relation between the length of a pendulum, its time period, the density of the bob and its mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity

I know that the motion of a pendulum does not depend on the mass of the bob. But if I am asked to find out the mass of the bob if the length of a pendulum, its time period and the density of the bob is given, how shall I do it? Please show me an equation or formula.

Comment: If the bob is not a point mass the angular acceleration is the torque divided by the moment of inertia, and the bob size and shape will affect the moment of inertia. The question presumably means you to calculate the bob size from the mass and density and hence get the moment of inertia.

Comment: -1. No research effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will get the following relations by using Newton's mechanics:

> $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\dfrac{L+r}{g}} \quad \Rightarrow  \quad r = f(T,L)$

so the mass of the bob will be

> $ m = \dfrac{4\pi}{3}\rho r^3 = \dfrac{4\pi}{3}\rho f(T,L)$.

Is this your wanted answer?

Comment: You should make the assumptions clear that go into this answer: It assumes that the bob is spherical and that the length of the pendulum _L_ is given as the length of the string only, not (as seems more reasonable) the distance of the centre of mass from the pivot. It's not clear from the question that these assumptions are justified.